# Вывести значение после перебора массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, объекты, методы

```
var list1 = [
    { firstName: 'Mark', lastName: 'G.', country: 'Scotland', continent: 'Europe', age: 22, language: 'JavaScript' },
    { firstName: 'Victoria', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Puerto Rico', continent: 'Americas', age: 30, language: 'Python' },
    { firstName: 'Emma', lastName: 'B.', country: 'Norway', continent: 'Europe', age: 19, language: 'Clojure' }
];
  
var list2 = [
    { firstName: 'Kseniya', lastName: 'T.', country: 'Belarus', continent: 'Europe', age: 29, language: 'JavaScript' },
    { firstName: 'Amar', lastName: 'V.', country: 'Bosnia and Herzegovina', continent: 'Europe', age: 32, language: 'Ruby' },
];


function getFirstPython(list) {
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const element = list[i];
        element.language == 'Python' ? alert(element.firstName + ", " + element.language) : alert('There will be no Python developers');
    }
}


getFirstPython(list1);
getFirstPython(list2);
```

Есть такой код. Нужно чтобы функция после проверки выводила < firstName here >, < country here > если в массиве есть хоть один участник со знанием языка Python или "There will be no Python developers." если такого нет.
Функция, которую я написал выводит результат проверки **каждого** элемента массива, а нужно чтобы после проверки целого массива.

Как переписать функцию?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getFirstPython(list) {
    let found = false;
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        const element = list[i];
        if (element.language == 'Python') {
            alert(element.firstName + ", " + element.language);
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
        alert('There will be no Python developers');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getFirstDeveloperWithLang(list, lang) {
    var allDevelopersWithLang = list.filter(developer => developer.language == lang);
    return allDevelopersWithLang.length ? allPythoners[0] : "There will be no Python developers";
}
```